# Using floats or doubles instead of ints

Tags: lua, floating-accuracy

I know that the default implementation of Lua uses floating point numbers only, thus circumventing the problem of dynamically determining the subtype of a number before choosing which variant of math function to use.

My question is -- if I try to emulate integers as doubles (or floats) in standard C99, is there a reliable (and simple) way to tell what is the maximum value representable precisely?

I mean, if I use 64-bit floats to represent integers, I certainly cannot represent all 64-bit integers (the pigeonhole principle applies here). How can I tell the maximum integer that is representable?

(Trying to list all values is not a solution -- if, for example, I'm using doubles in a 64-bit architecture, as I'd have to list 2^{64} numbers)

Thanks!

Comment: I think I should clarify one thing: I want a continuous range of numbers that could be precisely represented as floats (or doubles). The intention is to give up long, long long and int, and use floats (or doubles) only, but I need to know what my "MAX_REPREENTABLE_INTEGER" would be.

Comment: Lua 5.3, at the moment, is actually set to use integers for integral numbers unless you mix them with floating-point numbers or perform plain (non-integral) division. Exciting!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The maximum ones-representable integer is **2<sup>53</sup> (9007199254740992)** for a 64-bit double and 2<sup>24</sup> (16777216) for a 32-bit float. See the base digits on [the Wikipedia page for IEEE floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

Verifying this in Lua is pretty simple:

```lua
local maxdouble = 2^53

-- one less than the maximum can be represented precisely
print (string.format("%.0f",maxdouble-1)) --> 9007199254740991
-- the maximum itself can be represented precisely
print (string.format("%.0f",maxdouble))   --> 9007199254740992
-- one more than the maximum gets rounded down
print (string.format("%.0f",maxdouble+1)) --> 9007199254740992 again
```

If we don't have the IEEE-defined field sizes handy, knowing what we know about the *design* of floating point numbers, we can determine these values using a simple loop over the *possible* values:

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define min(a, b) (a < b ? a : b)
#define bits(type) (sizeof(type) * 8)
#define testimax(test_t) { \
  uintmax_t in = 1, out = 2; \
  size_t pow = 0, limit = min(bits(test_t), bits(uintmax_t)); \
  while (pow < limit && out == in + 1) { \
    in = in << 1; \
    out = (test_t) in + 1; \
    ++pow; \
  } \
  if (pow == limit) \
    puts(#test_t " is as precise as longest integer type"); \
  else printf(#test_t " conversion imprecise for 2^%d+1:\n" \
    "   in: %llu\n  out: %llu\n\n", pow, in + 1, out); \
}

int main(void)
{
    testimax(float);
    testimax(double);
    return 0;
}
```

[The output of the above code](http://codepad.org/tlzcufwh):

```
float conversion imprecise for 2^24+1:
   in: 16777217
  out: 16777216

double conversion imprecise for 2^53+1:
   in: 9007199254740993
  out: 9007199254740992
```

Of course, due to the way floating-point precision works, a 64-bit double can represent numbers much larger than 2<sup>64</sup> as the floating exponent grows positive. [The Wikipedia page on double-precision floating-point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) describes:

> Between 2<sup>52</sup>=4,503,599,627,370,496 and 2<sup>53</sup>=9,007,199,254,740,992 the representable numbers are exactly the integers. For the next range, from 2<sup>53</sup> to 2<sup>54</sup>, everything is multiplied by 2, so the representable numbers are the even ones, etc. Conversely, for the previous range from 2<sup>51</sup> to 2<sup>52</sup>, the spacing is 0.5, etc.

The *absolute largest* value a double can hold is listed further down that page: 0x7fefffffffffffff, which computes to (1 + (1 − 2<sup>−52</sup>)) * 2<sup>1023</sup>, or roughly 1.7976931348623157e308.

Comment: Yes, but I'd like a continuous range of exactly-representable-integers-as-floats. For example, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0 can be seen as "exact", but I don't know how farther I can go.

Comment: I cut this out of the main answer because it's mostly irrelevant, but the largest possible value for a double is listed in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Double-precision_examples - it's a little larger than a googol cubed.

Comment: It isn't correct to say that 2^53 is 'the maximum exact integer value'. It is the maximum value of the mantissa. There is nothing inexact about the FP representation of double that number, for example. 2^53 is however the correct answer *to the question,* as the OP is asking about a continuous range.

Answer (score 1):

The [IEEE floating point wikipage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) says:

> The original binary value will be preserved by converting to decimal and back again using:
>
> - 5 decimal digits for binary16
> - 9 decimal digits for binary32
> - 17 decimal digits for binary64
> - 36 decimal digits for binary128

Comment: That's for decimal string conversion, not the internal representation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at a conversion between int to float and back to int, it breaks down around 16,777,217 on my system (double didn't have any issues):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main (void)
{
  long in, out;
  double d;
  float f;

  for (in=0; in < (LONG_MAX); in++) {
    d=in;
    f=in;
    out=d;
    if (in != out) {
      printf ("Double conversion imprecise for %ld\n", in);
    }
    out=f;
    if (in != out) {
      printf ("Float conversion imprecise for %ld\n", in);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Two problems with this: 1. `long` isn't long enough to represent all the integral values for `double` , even if it were `unsigned` (`ULONG_MAX`, 2^32-1, is still smaller than 2^53). 2. Even if you were using `unsigned long long`, counting to 2^53 by ones will take approximately 18 days (taking the time it takes my computer to count to 2^29 and multiplying that by 2^24). See my solution for a much more practical loop.

Comment: Nice solution.  Even thinking of the IEEE floating point representation, I couldn't convince myself that it wouldn't break down somewhere between a power shift, though it's becoming obvious the more I think about it.  Good catch on the `long` not covering the full 64 bits requested in the question.